# It is neccessary to add .jks extension to keystore file?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-app-bundle, jks

I am creating bundle of my first app. I have followed a youtube tutorial in which they haven't added .jks extension to there keystore file while creating it and i have created my aab bundle using same instructions.

here is link to that tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4MXvMrbCTwA&t=766s

Now my question is will that keystore(without .jks extension) file work when i update my application. As i have seen in other tutorials that people used to save it with .jks extension.

Answer (score 1):

When you go to `Build > Generate Signed Bundle/APK.` the .jks extension is added by default.
The extension does not have to be given manually by you. You can also use it as many times you want to update your app

> Java Keystores (.jks or .keystore) are binary files that serve as repositories of certificates and private keys.

> A public key certificate (.der or .pem files), also known as a digital
> certificate or an identity certificate, contains the public key of a
> public/private key pair, as well as some other metadata identifying
> the owner  (for example, name and location) who holds the
> corresponding private key.

Ref: [Sign your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#sign-apk)

Comment: It is not added by default in my case. I am using mac system.

Comment: Go to the place where the file is generated and insect that .. The data type will be either a keystore file or a jks file

Answer (score 1):

**.JKS** extension to keystore file is not necessary, and yes, it will work with out any issue. You can signed APK/aab bundle to Play Store as many times as you want to upload to Play Store.

Comment: Will it cause any issue if i add .jks manully while generating keystore from android studio?